# rspec failing error: expected false to respond to `false?`

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I am running this portion of a test:

```
 describe Dictionary do
   before do
     @d = Dictionary.new
   end

    it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
        @d.include?('fish').should be_false
      end
```

With this code:

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end 

  def add(new_entry)
    new_entry.class == String ? @hash[new_entry] = nil : new_entry.each { |noun, definition| @hash[noun] = definition}    
  end 

  def entries
    @hash 
  end 

  def keywords
    @hash.keys
  end

  def include?(word)
    if @hash.has_key?(word)
      true
    else 
      false
    end 
  end 
end
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my tests keep failing and saying this:

```
> 1) Dictionary can check whether a given keyword exists
>      Failure/Error: @d.include?('fish').should be_false
>        expected false to respond to `false?`
```

I am confused at the error since it seems to be giving the correct answer. I would really appreciate if someone could take a few minutes to tell me what's wrong with my code. 
Thank you tons.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you browse the [RSpec Expectations 2.99](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-99/docs/built-in-matchers) and [RSpec Expectations 2.14](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers) and search the section - *Truthiness and existentialism*, you will find

```
expect(actual).to be_true  # passes if actual is truthy (not nil or false)
expect(actual).to be_false # passes if actual is falsy (nil or false)
# ...............
# ...
```

But of you browse [RSpec Expectations 3.0](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers) , the above method names got changed to -

```
expect(actual).to be_truthy    # passes if actual is truthy (not nil or false)
expect(actual).to be true      # passes if actual == true
expect(actual).to be_falsey    # passes if actual is falsy (nil or false)
# ...........
#......
```

It seems you are in **3.0**, and using the method which were exist prior to this version. Thus you were getting the error.

I put the code in my *test.rb* file as below :-

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end 

  def add(new_entry)
    new_entry.class == String ? @hash[new_entry] = nil : new_entry.each { |noun, definition| @hash[noun] = definition}    
  end 

  def entries
    @hash 
  end 

  def keywords
    @hash.keys
  end

  def include?(word)
    if @hash.has_key?(word)
      true
    else 
      false
    end 
  end 
end
```

And my *spec/test_spec.rb* file is -

```
require_relative "../test.rb"

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
  end
end
```

Now I am running the code from my console, and it works :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec -v
2.14.8
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec
.

Finished in 0.00169 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

---

Now I am changing the code in my **spec/test_spec.rb** file :-

```
require_relative "../test.rb"

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_falsey
  end
end
```

and again run the test :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec -v
2.14.8
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec
F

Failures:

  1) Dictionary can check whether a given keyword exists
     Failure/Error: @d.include?('fish').should be_falsey
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `falsey?' for false:FalseClass
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00179 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb:8 # Dictionary can check whether a given keyword exists
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

---

Now, they also mentioned in the [3.0.0.beta1 / 2013-11-07 changelog](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/changelog)

> Rename `be_true` and `be_false` to `be_truthy` and `be_falsey`. (Sam Phippen)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! It's fixed now :) I would vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: @user3417583 No issue,,, Enjoy Rspec!

Comment: It might be a slightly separate issue, but I found with v `2.99.0` these were flagged as deprecation warnings, so probably a lesson to be learned about bumping versions in your Gemfile somewhere in there as well. Certainly was for me!

Comment: I just solved another problem via your fantastic answer.Really helpful ,thank you.