# expected true to respond to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I upgraded my `rspec-rails` to 3.0.1 and now I'm seeing this error on all of my tests

```
 Failure/Error: Sidekiq::Status::complete?(json.jid).should be_true
  expected true to respond to `true?`
```

I can't find the solution nor what I'm missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rspec failing error: expected false to respond to \`false?\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937758/rspec-failing-error-expected-false-to-respond-to-false)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

From rspec 3.0, `be_true` is renamed to `be_truthy` and `be_false` to `be_falsey`

The behavior has not changed. So

```
(nil).should be_falsey
(false).should be_falsey
```

will pass, and

```
(anything other than nil or false).should be_truthy
```

will also pass

From the [changelog 3.0.0.beta1 / 2013-11-07](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/changelog)

> Rename be_true and be_false to be_truthy and be_falsey. (Sam Phippen)

Comment: Technically this answer is incorrect. rspec 3.0 `be_truthy` is not the same as `be true`.  If you truly want to check that the value is true and not just truthy, then you should use `expect(true).to be true` (note the lack of an underscore between be and true).  Ref: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

Comment: @LarryKyrala. You are right about `be true` being not same as `be_truthy`. But my answer and the OP's question was about `be_true` (note the presence of an underscore)

Comment: You are correct sir! I'm sorry, I didn't see that rename mentioned anywhere in the 3.0 docs. But it is in the [changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/commit/860ca42905582549768ee0ff0837fb6c523b8199).

Comment: The direct answer to this question can be very misleading, and should be appended with a clear note as mentioned by LarryKyrala . It wouldn't hurt if @Santhosh added a note to his answer explaining the subtle pitfall. This will help many avoid some serious misinterpretations.

Answer (score 1):

To not to rewrite lot of existing specs, you can add this to spec_helper (it harms my sense of harmony but saves time):

```
def true.true?
  true
end

def true.false?
  false
end

def false.true?
  false
end

def false.false?
  true
end
```

Comment: It's easy to find and replace this sort of thing. For example: `git grep -l be_true | xargs sed -i 's/be_true/be_truthy/'`