# TestFirst.org Dictionary Lesson Keyword Example Ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary, rspec, test-first

I am working through TestFirst.org's Ruby tutorial. I am currently on the "Dictionary" lesson. I am stuck on the keyword example. Here is the Ruby document as well as the RSpec file.

The reason I am confused is that I am not sure if the example is correct. If you follow the RSpec file, the examples before "can check whether a given keyword exists" uses the add method to add "fish" to the dictionary. Then, in the example that is given me an error,the include? method (which I need to implement) should return false.

Should it return false? Didn't we add "fish" in the examples above? Or am I missing something?

This is my Ruby program:

```
class Dictionary
    def initialize
        @entries = {}
    end

    def entries
        @entries
    end

    def keywords
        @entries.keys
    end

    def add(pairings)
        if pairings.is_a?(String)
            @entries[pairings] = nil 
        else
            pairings.each do |word, definition|
                @entries[word] = definition
            end
        end
    end

    def include?(keyword)
        @entries.keys.include?(keyword)
    end
end
```

The following is the RSpec file:
    # # Topics
    #
    # * Hash
    # * Array
    # * instance variables
    # * regular expressions
    #

```
require 'dictionary'

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
  end

  it "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false # if the method is empty, this test passes with nil returned
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fish').should be_true # confirms that it actually checks
    @d.include?('bird').should be_false # confirms not always returning true after add
  end

  it "doesn't include a prefix that wasn't added as a word in and of itself" do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fi').should be_false
  end

  it "doesn't find a word in empty dictionary" do
    @d.find('fi').should be_empty # {}
  end

  it 'finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing' do
    @d.add('fiend')
    @d.add('great')
    @d.find('nothing').should be_empty
  end

  it "finds an entry" do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
  end

  it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
    @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
    @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
  end

  it 'lists keywords alphabetically' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.keywords.should == %w(apple fish zebra)
  end

  it 'can produce printable output like so: [keyword] "definition"' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.printable.should == %Q{[apple] "fruit"\n[fish] "aquatic animal"\n[zebra] "African land animal with stripes"}
  end
end
```

Comment: This question has been asked before here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937758/rspec-failing-error-expected-false-to-respond-to-false

Answer (score 2):

The test is correct. What you're missing is how `before` works.

In RSpec, `before` hooks without arguments (or with the argument `:each`) specify steps to be taken before each test is run, not (as one might think) steps that are run before the entire set of tests.

In other words, the `before` hook runs before the first test, then before the second test, then before the third test, and so on.

The execution order looks like this:

1. **`before`**
2. `test1`
3. **`before`**
4. `test2`
5. **`before`**
6. `test3`

In your case, while it's true that in `it 'add keywords (without definition)' do` you add `'fish'` to `@d`, that doesn't affect the next test, because the `before` hook runs between the two of them, and replaces `@d` with a new, empty, `Dictionary` object. As a result, when testing `#include?`, you're checking if an empty `Dictionary` contains `'fish'`, which it doesn't.

If, instead, you wanted take some steps once, before any of the tests were run, you would replace your `before` block with:

```
before(:all) do
  @d = Dictionary.new
end
```

In that case, you'd be right; the test would be working with the same `Dictionary` as all the previous tests, and, consequently, should expect `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did not know how before worked in RSpec. The reason I am getting a problem at all is because I am using RSpec 3.0 when the tests were wrote with another version.

Comment: @user245185 You're absolutely right. I didn't mention it, because I didn't know what version you were using, and because it didn't seem important to your question, but, in RSpec 3.0, the tests should be written as `be_truthy` and `be_falsey`, respectively.